# Python create .exe from pyinstaller return error

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Hi guys we have an issue while creating the .exe file from the python script, We have issue when we include the sklern and other packages, It's work fine in the pychram but when we try to create the .exe file from the pyinstaller then it creates file but that file did not executed, When we debug the issue we find that its not be able to import the packages, Because each line that import the external package that returns error, If anyone can help us in it that will be great.

Comment: You need to use `--hidden-import` https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.1/usage.html#what-to-bundle-where-to-search

Comment: Please post the specific error you are encountering, and consider posting a minimal, complete example of your issue. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example